# Representing in a Jtable attributes from an object that is inside of another object. JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to represent in a `JTable` the attributes from an object that is inside of another object that is inside of a List. This attributes are a representation of data in my DB.

here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTAMENTO")
public class Departamento implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_ID_DPTO" )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_ID_DPTO")
@Column(name="ID_DPTO")
private long idDpto;

@Column(name="NOMBRE")
private String nombre;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_ZONA")
private Zona zona;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="departamento")
private List<Localidad> localidads;

public Departamento() {
}

public long getIdDpto() {
    return this.idDpto;
}

public void setIdDpto(long idDpto) {
    this.idDpto = idDpto;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Zona getZona() {
    return this.zona;
}

public void setZona(Zona zona) {
    this.zona = zona;
}

public List<Localidad> getLocalidads() {
    return this.localidads;
}

public void setLocalidads(List<Localidad> localidads) {
    this.localidads = localidads;
}

public Localidad addLocalidad(Localidad localidad) {
    getLocalidads().add(localidad);
    localidad.setDepartamento(this);

    return localidad;
}

public Localidad removeLocalidad(Localidad localidad) {
    getLocalidads().remove(localidad);
    localidad.setDepartamento(null);

    return localidad;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return nombre;
}

}
```

I get all this data through an EJB:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BeanDepartamento implements BeanDepartamentoRemote {


public BeanDepartamento() {

}

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public void crear(Departamento departamento) throws ServiciosException {
    try {
        em.persist(departamento);
        em.flush();
        System.out.println("Se creo departamento con Éxito");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se puedo crear departamento");
    }

}

@Override
public void actualizar(Departamento departamento) throws ServiciosException {
    try {
        Departamento d=em.find(Departamento.class, departamento.getIdDpto());
        em.detach(d);
        d.setNombre(departamento.getNombre());
        em.merge(d);
        em.flush();
        System.out.println("Departamento actualizado con éxito");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo crear departmaneto");
    }

}

@Override
public void borrar(Departamento departamento) throws ServiciosException {
    try {
        Departamento d=em.find(Departamento.class, departamento.getIdDpto());
        em.remove(d);
        em.flush();
        System.out.println("Departamento borrado con éxito");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar departamento");
    }
}

@Override
public List<Departamento> ObtenerTodos() {
    TypedQuery<Departamento> query=em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Departamento 
d",Departamento.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}

@Override
public void asignarZona(Departamento departamento, Zona zona) throws ServiciosException {
    try {
        Departamento d=em.find(Departamento.class, departamento.getIdDpto());
        d.setZona(em.find(Zona.class, zona.getIdZona()));
        em.flush();
        System.out.println("Zona asignada con éxito");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo asignar zona");
    }

}

@Override
public List<Departamento> ObtenerDepartamentoPorFiltro(String filtro) {
    TypedQuery<Departamento> query=em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Departamento d WHERE d.nombre LIKE 
:parametro",Departamento.class).setParameter("parametro", "%"+filtro+"%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
}
```

This is how I am trying to fill in my JTable:

```
public void mostrarDpto() {


        try {
            BeanDepartamentoRemote departamentoBean = (BeanDepartamentoRemote)
            InitialContext.doLookup("pdt- 
            final/BeanDepartamento!com.dmente.bean.BeanDepartamentoRemote");
            List<Departamento> Departamento= departamentoBean.ObtenerTodos();

            String[] columnas= {"ID", "Nombre","Zona"};

            Object matriz[][]=new Object[Departamento.size()][3];

            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
                matriz[i][0]=Long.toString(Departamento.get(i).getIdDpto());
                matriz[i][1]=Departamento.get(i).getNombre();
                matriz[i][2]=Departamento.get(i).getZona().toString(); //no me carga el nombre o id                 

            }





            tbMod.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                    matriz,columnas


                ));

            Departamento.clear();
        } catch (NamingException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }



 }
```

The problem is this line: `matriz[i][2]=Departamento.get(i).getZona().toString();`, when I run my project with this line my `JFrame` isnt't opening, but I don`t have any error message, if I comment this line, everything works fine(just don't show my`zona.name` attribute).

It's the first time working with swing, it's for a study project, so I kinda lost here for why is the reason that not represents this data in my `JTable`.

Comment: The problem is the line you said because you allocate 2 columns in array *matriz* and then trying to populate 3 columns (line with index 0, 1, and 2) in the *for* loop. Try allocating 3 columns for *matriz*.

Comment: sry, my bad. i forgot to edit that when I  copy/paste. I change that and keeps doing the same.

Comment: Maybe then your code gets stuck in `Zona.toString()`? I can't find the code of `Zona.toString()` in your provided code, but maybe there is the problem?... I don't know, but I'm guessing you should check it for infinite loops or something.

Comment: I'll check for that, but toString just return an attribute called nombre:

@Override
public String toString() {
    
    return nombre;
}

}

Comment: Ah ok then. Can you provide some more code? For example where is the creation of the JFrame? You may also put some printing statements (for debugging) around the assignment of the *matriz* array in the *for* loop: I mean, are you sure that there is where the whole program gets stuck?

Comment: I think you might find that it's easy to create your own `TableModel` which takes the `List<Localidad>` itself, rather then creating another array

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).